# ehcache exception when starting play 2.1 in PROD mode

Tags: playframework, ehcache

I'm using the play default cache in my application. When I try running my play 2.1 application using the target/start command on a server I get this error message:

net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Caches cannot be added by name when default cache config is not specified in the config. Please add a default cache config in the configuration.

Works fine in dev mode. Is there somewhere I need to specify a default cache?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace you're seeing, as well as some code snippets illustrating how you're using the Play and/or Ehcache API. This might help identify whether the error is being triggered from your code or possibly another library's interaction with Ehcache.

Comment: Sure. 
The stack trace I get is:
 Oops, cannot start the server.
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Caches cannot be added by name when default cache config is not specified in the config. Please add a default cache config in the configuration.
 at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:1167)
 at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.x$1$lzycompute(Cache.scala:122)
 at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.x$1(Cache.scala:120)
 

I'm calling Cache.set("key", "value"), and Cache.get("key")
Thanks

Comment: Only happens when running the app using the stage task.
so running target/start

it works fine running play start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack trace indicates that the exception is being thrown from Play Framework code that tries to programmatically create a cache called "play". As the [EhCache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq#what-does-the-following-error-mean-caches-cannot-be-added-by-name-when-default-cache-config-is-not-specified-in-the-config-please-add-a-default-cache-config-in-the-configuration) explains:

> When you try to programmatically add a cache by name, `CacheManager.add(String name)`, a default cache is expected to exist in the CacheManager configuration. To fix this error, add a defaultCache to the CacheManager's configuration.

The fix is simple enough - make sure the `ehcache.xml` file you are using has a `defaultcache` element (you can see what a `defaultcache` element looks like in Play 2.1's [default Ehcache configuration](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.1/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml)). The key question that still needs addressing is *which* configuration file is being used when you start up your application:

- If you've included an `ehcache.xml` file in the `conf` directory in your application, make sure it has a `defaultcache` element. Alternatively, if you don't have any of your own custom configuration in this file, you can considering deleting it and falling back to using Play's default configuration.
- If you don't have your own `ehcache.xml` file, search over the JAR files in your `staged` directory and see if any contain an `ehcache.xml` file.

As for why the error happens in some circumstances and not others, I would venture that there are classpath ordering differences between the various commands. This means that some commands will choose Play's internal Ehcache configuration (with the server then starting up cleanly), whereas others will load an incorrect Ehcache configuration file and spew out errors.